# rangeOfString:@"fReturnValue"].location == NSNotFound method never fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I already submitted the app into app store. So I cannot do any changes for front end code. But I want to change functionality of the App using Web Services (Backend code)

So I need to fire following if condition.

```
if (![returnValue rangeOfString:@"fReturnValue"].location == NSNotFound)
{
    returnValue = [_common getWebServiceResponseValueWithOutUnnecessary:returnValue withFieldName:@"fReturnValue"];
}
```

My return value is,

```
{"d":{"__type":"System.Data.DataTable","fReturnValue":"[{\"FldName\":\"PurchsOrdr\",\"TblName\":\"FCDOCHST\",\"Module\":\"Document\",\"Mandatory\":1,\"FldCaptn\":\"Purchase Order\",\"Editable\":0,\"CustomFld\":0}"}}
```

But this if condition is never true. Can't I True this if condition changing the json string?

Comment: @Bryan's answer is correct. Additionally, if this issue is critical for your app then either reject the binary (if not yet live) and/or submit a new one with correct client code.

Answer (score 2):

your code should be

```
if ([returnValue rangeOfString:@"fReturnValue"].location != NSNotFound)
```

but it is

```
if ((![returnValue rangeOfString:@"fReturnValue"].location) == NSNotFound)
```

which is similar to

```
NSInteger loc = [returnValue rangeOfString:@"fReturnValue"].location;
loc = !loc; // if loc is 0, it changed to 1, otherwise it changed to 0
if (loc == NSNotFound) // so this is not possible to be true
```

you should start making new version now... BTW how can you submit your app without testing it...

Comment: I found this issue after submitting it. :(